# Change colour of a table row on the basis of column value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am getting data using ng-repeat having a column status.I want to change the row colour on the basis of status ,i.e if the status is approved row colour is set to green and if status is rejected the row color is set to red.Can anyone help..Thanks in advance

Comment: You tag your question with JS, HTML, CSS and Angular, but I don't see a hint of any of these. Could you please provide some context?

Comment: can you please forget about the tag. I just want to achieve it in an html table @AlbertXing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a good practice to include some code snippet in your questions for us to understand your question better. Without it we can only do wild guesses that are most likely not you want or not suited for your style.

I assume your data is populated by `<tr>` in `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in tableData" ng-class="{approved: row.status == 1, rejected: row.status == 0}">
  <td>{{row.data1}}</td>
  <td>{{row.data2}}</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
tr.approved { background-color: green }
tr.rejected { background-color: red }
```

Above is a more proper way of applying a certain style to your data based on certain condition.

If you want quick and dirty way you can apply the style directly, too

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in tableData" ng-style="{'background-color': ((row.status == 1) ? 'green' : (row.status == 0) ? 'red' : '') }">
  <td>{{row.data1}}</td>
  <td>{{row.data2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: here is the code @lcycool                                 <tr ng-repeat="result in results "   >
                            <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
                            <td>{{result.companyName}}</td>
                            <td>{{result.createdAt}}</td>
                            <td>{{result.modifiedAt}}</td>
                            <td>{{result.Status}}</td>
                            <td>
      </tr>

Comment: Are you able to solve your problem using my example? It is similar to your code.

Comment: yup Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript/jquery here. Its easy! :) In your header tag, include the following for you to be able to use jQuery:

```
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then put this function inside your other `script` tag(just change the word "yourtableid" to the id of your table after the "#"):

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#yourtableid').find('td:contains("rejected ")').css('background-color','red');
        $('#yourtableid').find('td:contains("approved")').css('background-color','green');
```

});